# Double Tap needed for changing a buttons action

Tags: ios, xcode, uibutton, ibaction

I am testing this code.

```
    NSString *storyBoardName = @"Main";
    UIStoryboard *storyBoard =[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:storyBoardName bundle:nil];

    UIViewController *VC =[storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"T1"];
    [self presentViewController:VC animated:NO completion:nil];
```

It works fine, but the button needs to be pressed twice for this code to work. Is there any possibility of changing it to require only one tap?

Comment: I guess problem is `button`, not this code. Can you put more information about the button, please?

Comment: it's a normal UIButton that is in the storyboard.

Comment: Yes, but can you just confirm that button has not been resized, or it has sufficient touch area, just enable `Clip Subviews` property, and check whether you are able to access the button or, not.

Comment: Yes. I can definitely confirm

Comment: Is `Touch Down Repeat` what's trigger the IBAction?

Comment: Please use `"Touch up Inside"` as trigger for the button's `IBAction`.

Comment: Appears it was a bug. Now when I revisited it it works perfectly fine.